# How to read null from Date type column in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, date

I am trying to read a "termination date" column from an employee job table via hibernate. The column has date type DATE. The values are null for employees who do not have a termination date.

The problem was when I try to read a null terminate date, hibernate will somehow give me the current date as the response. However, if the date value is not null, hibernate will read the correct date.

I was wondering how to prevent hibernate from giving me the current date instead of null when terminate date is null. Thanks!

Below is how the column is mapped:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "terminationDate", column = @Column(name = Columns.TERMINATION_DT, nullable = true)) })
private PersonJob personJob;
.....
// PersonJob.java
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar terminationDate;
```

Comment: Which database u r using ?

Comment: @OO7 It's an Oracle database.

Comment: What do u want to save in that column `DATE`, `TIME` or `DATE & TIME` ? What is the version of ur Oracle ?

Comment: Which function u r using to fetch `terminationDate` from Oracle database ? What is version of ur `ojdbc*.jar` ? Have u tried to map `DATE` column to `java.util.Date` type ? Try removing `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` from the mapping so that `DATE` type map with `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Your column in database is of type `DATE` & you are mapping it to type [TemporalType.TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#TIMESTAMP) which means you are actually mapping it to [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

It is recommended that, if you have `column with TIMESTAMP` data type then for successful mapping in your entity class you have to map that attribute to [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

On the other side, if your database column is of type `DATE`, `TIME` or `DATETIME` then you can map it to [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [java.sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) or [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

But, [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) stores date & time. So you must clearly specify what is in your database `Date`, `TIME` or `both`.

**[From Hibernate DOCs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property):**

```
In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined. When dealing with 
temporal data you might want to describe the expected precision in database. Temporal 
data can have DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP precision (ie the actual date, only the time, 
or both). Use the @Temporal annotation to fine tune that.
```

You may want to look into Hibernate project code snippet of [TemporalTypeResolver.java](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.persistence.TemporalType).

**For MySQL :** [Here](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/the-best-practice-to-deal-with-datetime-in-mysql-using-jdbc.599436/) is good discussion on DateTime & Timestamp data.